# Trouble mapping multiple foreign keys to parent table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables, `users` and `contacts`. I query the `contacts` table and get a list of a user's contacts. I would then like to be able to write `Contact.first_name` (where `first_name` is a row from the `users` table) and print out that contact's first name.

Currently, my `Contact` object does not recognize any attributes of the `user` table.

Here is some code:

```
class User(Base):

    """ Basic User definition """

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(Unicode(255))
    last_name = Column(Unicode(255))

    contacts = relationship('Contact', backref='users')

class Contact(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'contacts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer)
    contact_id = Column(Integer)

    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint([id], [User.id]), {})
```

Here is my query:

```
Contact.query.filter(Contact.user_id == self.user_id).filter(Contact.state == True).all()
```

To be honest, I'm unsure of how to properly map my two foreign keys `Contact.user_id` and `Contact.contact_id` to the `User.id` row. Maybe this is the source of my problem?

I'm very new to using SQLAlchemy, so this is a learning experience here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is class `User` which essentially refers to itself.  In other words, it's a [self-referential many-to-many relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship).  Your model definitions should look like this:

```py
# This is so called association table, which links two tables in many-to-many
# relationship.  In this case it links same table's ('users') different rows.
user_contacts = Table(
    'user_contacts', Base.metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('contact_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True),
)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    contacts = relationship(
        'User',
        secondary=user_contacts,
        primaryjoin=id==user_contacts.c.user_id,
        secondaryjoin=id==user_contacts.c.contact_id
    )
```

Then you can do things like the following:

```py
u1 = User(first_name='Foo', last_name='Foo')
u2 = User(first_name='Bar', last_name='Bar')
u3 = User(first_name='Baz', last_name='Baz')
u1.contacts = [u2, u3]
session.add(u1)
session.commit()

# ... and in some other place in your code ...

u = User.query.get(1)
print u.contacts[0].first_name
```